# Linq to SQL Domain Entity Property Comparison Using Expressions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to create Linq to SQL expressions to generically allow for the same properties to be compared on two different domain entity records.  The general idea would be to define which properties on the entities need to be compared, then compare each of these properties one by one to check for equality/inequality.  I am identifying which properties need to be compared by creating expressions on the domain entities:

```
public class CompareEntityProperty<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> EntityPropertyExpression { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity, bool>> Compare
    {
        get
        {
            var expression = EntityPropertyExpression;
            return (entityA, entityB) => object.Equals(expression.Invoke(entityA), expression.Invoke(entityB));
        }
    }
}
```

Then to set this up for a generic entity, I would set it up as such:

```
public class foo : IEntity
{
    public long? bar { get; set; }
}
```

I would set it up using:

```
public class fooCompare
{
    public IEnumerable<CompareEntityProperty<foo>> CompareList
    {
        get
        {
            return new []
                {
                   new CompareEntityProperty<foo>() { EntityPropertyExpression = entity => entity.bar }
                };
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm seeing appears to be related to how my property expression is set up using 'object' as the type of the property.  When the expression is compiled, it attempts to convert the property type (in this case a nullable long to an object, which SQL does not know how to do and I get an error like:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'.

This appears to be confirmed when I add a watch and look at the expression that's actually generated:

> entity => Convert(entity.bar)

It looks like it is attempting to first convert the property value to a type that the 'object' type can work with, hence the error.

First, am I correct in my assumption about the error?  Is there a way around this?  Is there a way to set up the property expression to be dynamic rather than strongly typed to 'object'?  Or is there another option for skirting this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: I am using the LinqKit library, which provides the logic necessary to handle the 'Invoke' method call on the expression to be translated to SQL.

Comment: `expression.Invoke(entityA)` doesn't compile, because [`Expression.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb355170(v=VS.110).aspx) takes expressions as arguments. Are you using some kind of third-party library's extension methods or something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I'm using the LinqKit library, which provides the functionality for those sorts of calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library you're using to make your current code work for you, but if you want to generate Expressions by hand you're going to need to:

1. grab the `Body` from your EntityPropertyExpression

   ```
   entity.Bar
   ```
2. create a new ParameterExpression to represent your second lambda parameter.
3. use an expression tree visitor to create a new expression that replaces instances of the lambda parameter with instances of a new parameter

   ```
   entity2.Bar
   ```
4. Use `Expression.Call()` to generate a method call to the `Equals` method, passing in the two member expressions

   ```
   object.Equals(entity.Bar, entity2.Bar)
   ```
5. Use `Expression.AndAlso()` to combine any number of these expression trees together:

   ```
   object.Equals(entity.Foo, entity2.Foo) &&
   object.Equals(entity.Bar, entity2.Bar) &&
   object.Equals(entity.Baz, entity2.Baz)
   ```
6. Use `Expression.Lambda<>()` to generate a new lambda expression that takes the two parameters and applies them to the expression you've built:

   ```
   (entity, entity2) => 
       object.Equals(entity.Foo, entity2.Foo) &&
       object.Equals(entity.Bar, entity2.Bar) &&
       object.Equals(entity.Baz, entity2.Baz)
   ```

If Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL are having issues with the concept of translating values into `object`s to pass into `object.Equals()`, you'll probably need to use reflection in step 4 above to find the appropriate `.Equals()` instance method and call that instead.